# Stokes Theorem for Manifolds with Self-Intersections

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, geometric-measure-theory, stokes-theorem

I am trying to find some reference regarding some generalizations of Stokes Theorem. I could simply state it as follows:

> Assume $D_1$ is a $C^1$ 2-disk with a piecewise $C^1$ boundary $S_1$ and assume you glue another disk $C^1$ 2-disk $D_2$ with a piecewise $C^1$ boundary $S_2$ along their boundaries. If $D_1$ and $D_2$ do not intersect then the new object bounds a 3 sphere $X$ and then for any smooth differential 1-form $\alpha,$ we have $\int_{D_1 \cup D_2} d\alpha = \int_{X}dd\alpha=0$ by Stokes theorem.
>
> Now what happens if $D_1$ and $D_2$ have intersections? Are there anologues of Stokes theorem for this case?

I did some research and there are various other generalizations but for this case I could only find a single source which claims it works without reference. So I probably dont know the correct key words (I searched Stokes theorem for manifolds with self intersection).

I guess in case the intersections are "simple" you can always chop up things and work with simpler objects but I am not sure how bad the intersections can look like. Also if there are intersections what is the corrrect way to define the interior of $D_1 \cup D_2$? I guess field of normals to the surface would still be defined which you can use to define the interior but I am lacking basic tools to understand this issue formally. So I would be very grateful for any reference on Stokes theorem for this generality so I can learn the tools of trade.

Comment: I have edited your question to be a little more readable. I have also noticed that you have an additional question mark in the final paragraph; you should consider reorganizing your post to make your questions more obvious to the reader. You might consider asking for resources/references in a *separate* question, and including the (reference-request) tag on that question.

Comment: If you allow intersections, then the result could be a Klein bottle, where it is difficult indeed to define any interior. (And there is no nonvanishing field of normals!)

Comment: Hmm this was useful thanks, made me remember of the concept of a density on a manifold which could be some useful keyword for me.

Comment: If you're just trying to make this conclusion, why not go the other way? i.e. $\int_{D_1 \cup D_2} d \alpha = \int_{\partial(D_1 \cup D_2)} \alpha = 0$ since $D_1 + D_2$ is a closed chain.

Comment: Well thanks but this is just a particular question that I have in mind. I want to generally educate myself on how one approaches such situations where you are not working with manifolds. But your remark makes me think that I should probably just look up proof of Stokes theorem from a book on more algebraic topology perspective.